# Многострочный текст в Си

Tags: c

Добрый день. У меня такое задание:

Из введенного пользователем многострочного текста распечатать только те слова, в которых буквы упорядочены по алфавиту.
 (Для решения не использовать стандартные строковые функции)

Как вообще ввести с консоли многострочный текст и как его хранить?

Я так понимаю, что при вводе многосторочного текста я ввожу одну строку, нажимаю Enter, ввожу следующую, нажимаю Enter, и так пока не надоест. Правильно? То есть мне нужен массив массивов чаров, чтобы хранить введенный текст?

Comment: Просто читайте по словам

    while (scanf("%s", word) == 1) {
       if (in_order(word))
         fprintf(outfile, "%s\n", word);
    }

до конца файла (при вводе с клавиатуры ^D в \*nix или ^Z в винде).

`scanf()` ведь пропускает концы строк.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов того, как это можно сделать. Вариант "в лоб": просто читать по одному символу

```
char data_in[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
size_t cur_char_pos = 0;
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
    data_in[cur_char_pos] = c;
    if ( isSpace(c) )
        processWord(data_in,cur_char_pos);
    cur_char_pos = 0;
}
if ( isSpace(c) )
    processWord(data_in,cur_char_pos);
```

Где `processWord` это функция, которая принимает массив `char` и длину слова, затем производит обработку слова. В таком случае, приложение будет читать ввод до получения `EOF` -- это Ctrl+D в Linux или Ctrl+Z в Windiows.